# Pinch to zoom imageview inside scrollview causes image to reposition to top left

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

My goal is to allow the uiimageview to be resized and moved, while inside a uiscrollview.

I've placed a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView as per: https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/pinch-to-zoom-uiimageview-with-swift

The pinching and zooming works as expected - but the problem is: **after I resize the image and release my "pinch", the image view moves to the top left corner of the scroll view.**

*What I want instead, is for the image to stay in it's place when I release the pinch.*

I'm guessing that my autolayout constraints in the xib are causing this, and I've read through many stackoverflow questions on the topic - but nothing is fixing this behavior

Any suggestions on how to fix the problem?  Or do you recommend a different approach than the one offered by the link posted above?

Comment: Hey, come to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Comment: @Alan did you find the solution for that?